# How to trace the path of a double pendulum in javascript?

Tags: javascript, simulation, physics

I have been writing a double pendulum simulation recently and the simulation works perfectly well. However, I want to trace the path of the double pendulum. But, I'm unsure of how to do that without removing the "clearRect()" function which would make the pendulum's arms refresh as well.

I have tried making an array of previous (x,y) coordinates and putting dots on those coordinates. But, that didn't function as a solution. Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/av6ewtnr/19/

```
var canvas, ctx, width, height,
    p1 = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        angle: Math.PI/2,
        angle_v: 0,
        angle_a: 0,
        length: 100,
        mass: 100
    },
    p2 = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        angle: Math.PI/2,
        angle_v: 0,
        angle_a: 0,
        length: 100,
        mass: 100
    },

    g = 1;

    function main () {
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        width = canvas.width = 600;
        height = canvas.height = 600;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        loop();
    }

    function loop () {
        var loop = function () {
            update();
            draw();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop,canvas);
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop,canvas);
    }

    function update () {
        p1.angle_a = (-g*(2*p1.mass+p2.mass)*Math.sin(p1.angle)-p2.mass*g*Math.sin(p1.angle-p2.angle)-2*Math.sin(p1.angle-p2.angle)*p2.mass*(p2.angle_v*p2.angle_v*p2.length+p1.angle_v*p1.angle_v*Math.cos(p1.angle-p2.angle)))/(p1.length*(2*p1.mass+p2.mass-p2.mass*Math.cos(2*p1.angle-2*p2.angle)));
        p2.angle_a = (2*Math.sin(p1.angle-p2.angle)*(p1.angle_v*p1.angle_v*p1.length*(p1.mass+p2.mass)+g*(p1.mass+p2.mass)*Math.cos(p1.angle)+p2.angle_v*p2.angle_v*p2.length*p2.mass*Math.cos(p1.angle-p2.angle)))/(p2.length*(2*p1.mass+p2.mass-p2.mass*Math.cos(2*p1.angle-2*p2.angle)));

        p1.angle_v += p1.angle_a;
        p1.angle += p1.angle_v;

        p2.angle_v += p2.angle_a;
        p2.angle += p2.angle_v;

        p1.angle_v *= 0.999;
        p2.angle_v *= 0.999;

        p1.x = p1.length * Math.sin(p1.angle);
        p1.y = p1.length * Math.cos(p1.angle);

        p2.x = p1.x + p2.length * Math.sin(p2.angle);
        p2.y = p1.y + p2.length * Math.cos(p2.angle);
    }

    function draw () {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(300,200);

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'cornflowerblue';
        ctx.lineWidth = 7;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
        ctx.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();
    }

    main();
```

Comment: Your solution is O(n) but if you have a second but invisible buffer, you can draw onto it for each new position and then blit it onto original buffer after clearRect. Since invisible buffer doesnt need clearRect, it is O(1) for every frame.

Comment: OML, thanks! That was really helpful and it worked :)